# Probability of picking 50 people and 40 of them are women.

Tags: probability

I have **835 people**. **400** of them are **women**. **435** of them are **men**.

I pick randomly 50 people.

**i)  What's the probability of picking exactly 40 women among the 50 people.**

Comment: When you pose a question here, you should include your attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Binomial probability calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have ${ 835 \choose 50}$ total options.

To choose exactly 40 women (and exactly 10 men) can be done in ${400 \choose 40}{435 \choose 10}$ ways.

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways to pick $40$ out of $400$ women is $\binom{400}{40}$

The number of ways to pick $10$ out of $435$ men is $\binom{435}{10}$

The number of ways to pick $50$ out of $835$ people is $\binom{835}{50}$

Hence the probability is $\dfrac{\binom{400}{40}\cdot\binom{435}{10}}{\binom{835}{50}}$